# In jQuery, how do you add code to an already bound element?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have an element (e.g `$('#elm')` ) and it has a binding on it in the source code.

E.G. `$('#elm').on('touchstart', function(){ /* do stuff */ });`

Now I am adding more code to the page and I want to add new functionality to the binding of the element, WITHOUT removing the previous `do stuff` code.

How can I add code to the #elm `touchstart` binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#elm').on('touchstart', function () { /* do stuff */ });
$('#elm').on('touchstart', function () { /* do other stuff */ });
```

Use as many event handlers as you like.

Comment: You are right, my code is getting into the binding correctly, it's just not running my new code. I will have to debug that. Thank you!

Comment: Make sure that the two event handlers are completely independent of each other. That means no global variables, no shared state.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The cod ended up not running correctly because I needed to place it below the first binded code and I also forgot to put a period for one of my selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple handlers attached to an element, it's completely fine. They'll execute in the order they were attached.

So just

```
$("#elm").on("touchstart", function() { /* new stuff */ });
```

Example using `click`:

```js
$("#elm").on("click", function() {
  console.log("The first handler");
});
$("#elm").on("click", function() {
  console.log("The second handler");
});
```

```html
<div id="elm">Click me</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are right, my code is getting into the binding correctly, it's just not running my new code. I will have to debug that. Thank you!

Comment: @rjg132234: If the previous handler uses [`event.stopImmediatePropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/), that would prevent a subsequent handler from being run. At that point, you'd have to go into undocumented internals to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.